# Camel - stream:file and ftp upload

Tags: apache-camel

I have a Camel/Spring Boot app which retrieves data from a GraphQL endpoint, stores the data in an in-memory database (2 tables), extracts a CSV file by running a SQL query and is then supposed to upload the file to an FTP server. Since there's ~350k records which will be extracted I am using SQLs outputType=StreamList, splitter and stream:file. The full route looks like this:

```
from("direct:loadComplete").id("loadComplete")
    .log("${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ} - Load complete")
    .setHeader("createDate", simple("${date:now:yyyyMMdd'_'HHmmss}"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME,simple("${header.createDate}_sku_{{account.countryCode}}.csv"))
    .to("sql:"+ QUERY + "?outputType=StreamList") //run the SQL query
    .split(body()).streaming() //stream & split the results
        .bean(LineProcessor.class, "processLine") //process each entry and transform to CSV
        .toD("stream:file?fileName={{setting.outputDir}}/${header.CamelFileName}&closeOnDone=true") // stream each record to file
    .end()
    .log("${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ} - Written file to disk:${header.CamelFileName}")
    .to("ftp://{{ftp.host}}:{{ftp.port}}/{{ftp.path}}?fileName={{setting.outputDir}}/${header.CamelFileName}&username={{ftp.username}}&password={{ftp.password}}&{{ftp.config}}") // upload the CSV file
    .log("${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ} - FTP upload complete. File: ${header.CamelFileName}");
```

The data is extracted without any issue and the CSV file is created with the records. However, the upload to the FTP server fails with
*Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: org.apache.camel.component.sql.ResultSetIterator*
I believe this is due to the file streaming. Is there any way to execute the ftp upload once the stream:file is complete and have a follow up rout on the "closeOnDone"?

On another note I would be interested how the *outputType=StreamList* actually works in the background. I assume it still loads the full SQL result into memory? Are there any other ways to minimize the memory consumption of the application and not have large payloads being passed around? Any other ways to do this more elegantly and use the CSV marshalling?

Thanks for the help!

Holger

Answer (score 0):

In stream processing you uploading created csv rows to local file. After ".end()" body will contains result of sql producer. You should read data from local file for FTP producer.

```
from("direct:loadComplete").id("loadComplete")
            .log("${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ} - Load complete")
            .setHeader("createDate", simple("${date:now:yyyyMMdd'_'HHmmss}"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME,simple("${header.createDate}_sku_{{account.countryCode}}.csv"))
            .to("sql:"+ QUERY + "?outputType=StreamList") //run the SQL query
            .split(body()).streaming() //stream & split the results
            .bean(LineProcessor.class, "processLine") //process each entry and transform to CSV
            .toD("stream:file?fileName={{setting.outputDir}}/${header.CamelFileName}&closeOnDone=true") // stream each record to file
            .end()
            .log("${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ} - Written file to disk:${header.CamelFileName}")
            .pollEnrich("file:{{setting.outputDir}}?fileName=${header.CamelFileName}&noop=true", 10000/*investigate about timing according your file size*/, new AggregationStrategy() {
                @Override
                public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
                    return newExchange;// save important data from old exchange
                }
            })
            .to("ftp://{{ftp.host}}:{{ftp.port}}/{{ftp.path}}?fileName={{setting.outputDir}}/${header.CamelFileName}&username={{ftp.username}}&password={{ftp.password}}&{{ftp.config}}") // upload the CSV file
            .log("${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ} - FTP upload complete. File: ${header.CamelFileName}");
```

Comment: Upd: PollEnrich consumer will care about reusing same file. By default noop=true will leave local file at same place, but will enable in memory idempotent repository. If next exchange from "direct:loadComplete" will have same ${header.CamelFileName} you will get old exception.